# Delay Java initialization until needed

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a web page where sometimes I need to communicate with a device.
This device is accessed with sockets, so I have a jar file with the support libraries.

When you want to get data from the device, you press a button, and a javascript method fetches the data using the library (no java code here)

The presence of the jar makes the java machine to start as soon as you load the page.

Since there is a lot of users that don't use this option (usually they don't even have the device, to begin with), they see that as a nuisance.

Is there a posibility to delay the java loading until the button is pressed ?

I don't want to redirect them to another page, that should be done in the same page.

Comment: You could remove your `applet` or `object` tags from the initial html, and instead append them to the DOM during the button's `onclick`.

Comment: This comment is better than the only answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the jar file into a seperate div created dynamically via javascript, at the time you need it.

Comment: Doing it this way, is it ok to run my javascript code in the onload of the dynamic div ? Or should I add some delay to allow for the java start - between the jar loading and the library is available ?

Comment: Not really, I was thinking that creating a dynamic div with the jar and using it immediately could give me problems

Comment: Frankly, I do not know. If your jar needs data from js in dynamic div that it is loaded together, there should be a handshake between them (js and java). So I would be writing the js functions in the dynamic div content prior to <applet ... Then make your java code find and call a js function when loaded, if you want to be sure.

Comment: Sometimes life is easier than expected. Works perfect without need to delay until load or similar. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider loading your application with java-webstart-technology, you can implement a button similiar to what oracle has on their page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

Basically what the button does is download the required jars specified in a jnlp-file and launch it.